# How do i create sqlite DB without using WebSQL API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do i create SQLite DB without using WebSQL API?(for Google Chrome browser).
i want to create synchronized API for SQLite database .
Using Extensions if it is possible
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There's no secondary interface to SQLite inside of Chrome that extensions generally have access to; WebSQL is it. You might want to take a look at the [Storage API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/storage.html), which gives you a syncable data-storage system that looks a lot like local storage. Perhaps that suits your use-case?